# I started learning JavaScript and I have a problem with if statement

Tags: javascript

I started learning JavaScript and I want to do my own small project 'BMI calculator' but I can't find an error with my if statement.
Everything working fine but if as a input I will type for example 0, I don't see any warning message instead I see result of calculation.

```js
function sum() {

  var num1 = +document.getElementById('height').value;
  if (num1 <= 0) {
    var text1 = " Wrong Height Input "
    document.getElementById('messagePanel').innerHTML = text1;
  }
  var num2 = +document.getElementById('weight').value;
  if (num2 <= 0) {
    var text2 = " Wrong Weight Input "
    document.getElementById('messagePanel').innerHTML = text2;
  }
  var num1 = num1 / 100;
  var sum = num2 / (num1 * num1);
  var fixedSum = sum.toFixed(1);
  document.getElementById('messagePanel').innerHTML = fixedSum;

}
```

```html
Height: <input id="height">
<br> Weight: <input id="weight">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="sum()">
<br> BMI:
<div id="messagePanel"></div>
```

Comment: When the system rejected your title, the idea was that you'd write a halfway useful one instead, not just spam garbage.

Comment: Putting 0 into this function has it produce the result of the calculation, as expected. Did you mean to use "less-than" `<` rather than "less-than-or-equal-to" `<=`?

Comment: for each `xxx.innerHTML = something`, consider changing to `xxx.innerHTML += "<p>" + something + "</p>`.  The message will include ALL messages.  The `<p>`/`</p>` is the simplest way I could think of for line separation.  Notice the `+=` - it appends to what's already there.

Comment: I'd change `sum` to `bmi`...

Comment: I'd also let the user know that height is to be inputted in meters-decimal-centimeters and that weight is in kilograms.

Comment: Instead of "wrong" I'd say something like "anti-matter has not yet been discovered: please enter a positive weight" and something similar for height... :)  Also, I'd check for ranges for which this bmi calculation actually makes sense - say: 1.20-2.10m and 40-150kg (300 in USA... :) ).

Comment: Also, what if user entered non-digits (and period `.`)?

Comment: Thank you all. I really appreciate this.

Comment: iAmOren thank you for all your tips but I started this project around 30 min ago so I will try to fix everything soon

Comment: @Krystian25 good luck!  Let me know if I can help more!  hint: +xxxxxxx.value can return NaN (Not a Number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't stop the function when you detect invalid input. You put the error message into the message panel, but then you continue to the code that performs the calculation with the invalid input.

You should return from the function after displaying the error message.

```js
function sum() {

  var num1 = +document.getElementById('height').value;
  if (num1 <= 0) {
    var text1 = " Wrong Height Input "
    document.getElementById('messagePanel').innerHTML = text1;
    return;
  }
  var num2 = +document.getElementById('weight').value;
  if (num2 <= 0) {
    var text2 = " Wrong Weight Input "
    document.getElementById('messagePanel').innerHTML = text2;
    return;
  }
  var num1 = num1 / 100;
  var sum = num2 / (num1 * num1);
  var fixedSum = sum.toFixed(1);
  document.getElementById('messagePanel').innerHTML = fixedSum;

}
```

```html
Height: <input type="number" id="height">
<br> Weight: <input type="number" id="weight">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="sum()">
<br> BMI:
<div id="messagePanel"></div>
```